# Why this definition of spherical contact distribution function is $1 - N(b(o,r) =0)$ and not $N(b(o,r) =0)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, point-processes

I've been doing some reading on spatial Poisson point processes on my own tonight, and right now having a headache or a brainwarp or I don't know what because I don't get this definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_contact_distribution_function):

> The spherical contact distribution function is defined as:
>
> $H_s ( r ) = 1 − P ( N ( b ( o , r ) ) = 0 )$
>
> where $b(o,r)$ is a ball with radius$ r$ centered at the origin $o$. In other words, spherical contact distribution function is the probability there are no points from the point process located in a hyper-sphere of radius $r$.

In case of homogenous Poisson process, I can see how that $P ( N ( b ( o , r ) ) = 0 )= e^{-\lambda |b(o,r)|}$. The thing I don't get is: why do we subtract this term from $1$?

By construction, isn't $P ( N ( b ( o , r ) ) = 0 )$ alone itself the probability that number of points in a sphere with radius $r$ is $0$. Isn't this exactly what the textual description of definition states?

Answer (score 0):

From that wiki page you shared in your question: "More specifically, a spherical contact distribution function is defined as probability distribution of the radius of a sphere when it first encounters or makes contact with a point in a point process." - Thus it depicts the probability when there is at least one count of point process point(s) within the spacial ball of $b(o,r)$.

Since $\mathbb P(N(b(o,r)=0)$ is the probability of zero points within $b(o,r)$, you do $1-\mathbb P(N(b(o,r)=0)$.

I am recently also learning it. I am reading [Liniger 2009](https://www.research-collection.ethz.ch/bitstream/handle/20.500.11850/151886/eth-1112-02.pdf), and I recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still confused. As you said, it gives the probability for there being a point anywhere within the ball. But if we are interested in probability that the sphere b(o,r)  first encounters one or several points of process $X$, shouldn't we look at the probability $P(N(b(o,r -\epsilon) = 0 \cap N(\mathbf{R}^2 \setminus b(o,r -\epsilon)) > 0)$? While $P(N(b(o,r) > 0)$ could be seen as a CDF $P(d(o,X) \leq r)$. edit. or maybe the definition in the article has been talking about this CDF all the time and I've been unnecessarily confused by terminology.